# R Shuffle values in columns 3-6 based on values in columns 1 AND 2

Tags: r, shuffle

I am very new to R and I really try to get better, but I have been stuck on the following problem for some time now:

I have a data frame with let's say 6 columns and 20 rows. What I need to do is shuffle my data per column, but only for columns 3-6 based on the values of columns 1 AND 2.

I will try to give an example to make it more clear: I am dealing with two quantified transcripts of two speakers each. So column 1 is a number for the Talk, column 2 is a number for the speaker. So now I need to filter my data by Talk and Speaker and then randomly shuffle my data in all other columns. And I need to repeat this for all talks and all speakers.

Does anyone have any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[sample(seq_along(x))]), .(Talk, Speaker)]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Talk, Speaker) %>% 
   mutate_each(funs(.[sample(row_number())]))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(49)
df1 <- data.frame(Talk = rep(1:3, each = 3), Speaker = sample(1:3, 9,
 replace=TRUE), col3 = rnorm(9), col4 = rnorm(9), col5 = rnorm(9), col6 = rnorm(9))
```

Comment: I tried both but I cannot get them to work - the packages produce errors.

Comment: @LenaMüller  You haven't provided any reproducible example.  But, if you check the data in my post (which I reproduced), it is working for me.

Comment: Ok, with your example data I get it to work and it does exactly what I need. I'll try on my data again. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to adapt it for my data set df1 <- data.frame(Talk = rep(1:37, each = 37), Speaker = sample(1:37, 19358, replace=TRUE), "Pronoun" = rnorm(19358), "I" = rnorm(19358), "We" = rnorm(19358),"Self" = rnorm(19358), "You" = rnorm(19358), "Other" = rnorm(19358), "Negate" = rnorm (19358), "Assent" = rnorm(19358), "Article" = rnorm(19358), "Preps" = rnorm(19358), "Number"=rnorm(19358), "Swear"=rnorm(19358), "Nonfl"=rnorm(19358), "Fillers"=rnorm(19358))
Error in data.frame(Talk = rep(1:37, each = 37), Speaker = sample(1:37,  : 
  Argumente implizieren unterschiedliche Anzahl Zeilen: 1369, 19358

Comment: But it produces the error below which means that there's a different amount of rows implied in the arguments...

Comment: @LenaMüller  The dataset you created have unequal column lengths `length(rep(1:37, each = 37))#
[1] 1369` and `19358`

Comment: yeah, that's true, because all of my conversations have different lengths = different numbers of rows. Can I somehow consider this?

Comment: @LenaMüller  It is not possible for a `data.frame` as columns all have the same length.  Perhaps you have a `list`?

Comment: It is a table I imported from excel which I tried to convert into a data.frame using as.data.frame.matrix(mytable) - still not working. I am very sorry, I somehow cannot get my head around it...